# How to add product list on left side and checkout summary right sidebar in custom page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to create a custom page in my custom module which is having product listing on main container and Order summary panel (just like checkout page) as right sidebar so that user can add product and see the result on cart sidebar.

Comment: Have u tried? anythings

Comment: I have copy pasted checkout_index_index.xml contents into my layout xml but that is very large file and if i remove other then sidebar code, it only shows loader when page loads.